# sql query to fetch multiple rows from a table matching in two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 2 columns in which one column is unique. I want to fetch records from table as below, I want to query from my sql developer to fetch records from the table where transaction id = 195865487, 201263012 and transaction sequence is 
1,4,5,6,7 for 195865487 and 2,3,4,5,6,7 for 201263012 .

```
transaction id  | transaction seq
----+-----------+-------------------                                              
195865487       |  1
201263012       |  1   
195865487       |  2
195865487       |  3
195865487       |  4
195865487       |  5
195865487       |  6
195865487       |  7
195865487       |  8 
201263012       |  2  
201263012       |  3  
201263012       |  4  
201263012       |  5  
201263012       |  6  
201263012       |  7 
201263012       |  8  
201263012       |  9
```

Comment: Please show the example results you want, at present I can't figure out what you're trying to describe.  Also, why did you put `201263012,1` in second row of your example data, rather than just before `201263012,2`?  Is that significant in some way?  *(Is there another column, such as a timestamp, that determines that position?)*  You then mention `transaction sequence is 1,4,5,6,7`, but your sample data has no such sequence?

Comment: Please re-read you question and consider if you would understand it without prior knowledge.

Comment: results I'm excepting are  transaction id  | transaction seq
----+-----------+-------------------                                              
195865487       |  1 195865487       |  4 195865487       |  5 195865487       | 6 195865487       |  7
201263012       |  2  201263012       |  4 201263012       |  5 201263012       |  6 201263012       | 7

Comment: transaction sequence? In any order? Or does your table have a timestamp column as well?

Comment: transaction sequence in any order. I do not have a timestamp in the table.

Comment: If you delete the (201263012, 5) row, you don't want any 201263012 rows at all? (Or do you still want the 2,3,4,6,7 rows?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct `where` condition like this:

```
select * from t 
  where (transaction_id = 195865487 and transaction_seq in (1,4,5,6,7))
     or (transaction_id = 201263012 and transaction_seq in (2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0a1448cbd6c643e12d4195e542aa0b77)</sup>**

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT * FROM some_table
WHERE transaction_id IN (195865487, 201263012)
AND (transaction_sequence IN (1,4,5,6,7)
OR transaction_sequence IN (2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the required results

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (transaction_id=195865487 AND transaction_seq IN (1,4,5,6,7))
OR (transaction_id=201263012 AND transaction_seq IN (2,3,4,5,6,7))
```